# unique xpath for element span inside div inside button selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[Xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIWSh.png)

I'm looking for Unique Xpath for this element (Select)
in google language settings
https://myaccount.google.com/language?hl=en
already have this xpath but I need something more accurate and unique

```py
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
            "//*[@id='yDmH0d']/div[11]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button"))).click()
```

Comment: This xpath locates de button on browser, let me know if it works for you: `//div[child::div[.="Add Language"]]/descendant::button[@aria-label="Select your language"]`

Comment: what's the error? did you selected a language before clicking the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pay attention to the HTMLDOM :

You can construct a `xpath` based on **attribute name** only. You do not need their `values` nor `their text`.

```
//div[@data-is-touch-wrapper]/button[@data-id and @aria-label]
```

represent two matching nodes.

```
(//div[@data-is-touch-wrapper]/button[@data-id and @aria-label])[2]
```

should get the job done.

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@data-is-touch-wrapper]/button[@data-id and @aria-label])[2]"))).click()`  this one work fine  like this is it ok ?

Comment: Yes it is. There no harm in xpath indexing. Let me know when you execute this and face any issue.

Comment: no issue but because "(//div[@data-is-touch-wrapper]/button[@data-id and @aria-label])[2]" is it rights like this in code with ()

Comment: Yes of course it is.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to copy the X-Path from the Browser as discribed here:
[Mozilla Help](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-can-i-get-the-xpath-of-an-element-in-developer-tools-as-firebug-is-not-supported-in-latest-ff/25934/4)

My result would be: `//*[@id="lang-selector"]`